# MongoDB Few-To-Few Association

Tags: mongodb, many-to-many, nosql

This is a follow-up question on [MongoDB : where is the limit between "few" and "many"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438853/mongodb-where-is-the-limit-between-few-and-many/31440610#31440610).

I come from the relational database world and I am now working on a new NoSQL project with MongoDB.

**EDIT**: I was working on this project with *Rails*, and decided to move to *Meteor* for prototyping, which requires to use *MongoDB*. I am providing the below information to explain what I had come up with in terms of database schema when working on the *Rails* version of the project.

This project will be based on the following collections:

```
User
  firstName
  lastName
  emailAddress
  password     

Calendar
  title

Role
  userId
  calendarId

Post
  calendarId
  date
  time
  focus
  format
  blogTitle
  longCopy
  shortCopy
  link
  hashtag
  media
  promotion
  target
  approval
  comment
```

A `user` will be able to create and manage several `calendars` and a `calendar` will allow several `users` to collaborate.

I believe this will be a `few-to-few` (not a `many-to-many`) association since:

- A `user` should not have more than a couple dozens `calendars`
- A `calendar` should not have more a dozen `users`

The access pattern will be the following:

- A user will log in, and will automatically be presented with a list of his calendars.
- The main action of the `user` will be to choose a `calendar` and edit its content (CRUD `posts` within this given calendar).
- Sometimes, but definitely not within every session, the `user` will need to access and CRUD the list of `users` belonging to one of his `calendars`.

What would be the best way to structure such a project with MongoDB?

Comment: Can I "suggest" that considering you didn't really get an "answer" that "solved" that question you are "following up" from that you might at least glean something from the commentary given there. MongoDB and "NoSQL" ( not a real tag IMHO ) in general is **not** about relational concepts at all. The general idea is "denormalize" and do so for performance. That said, we all use these things because "we already know the denormalized form suits us best" ( for our cases ). If you are not there yet, then you need to work with your app more, and either get there or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am sorry if my question was not asked with the right angle, I did not mean to offense anybody or make any waste their time. I definitely understand that MongoDB is about denormalization and I am not trying to use a relational schema with it. I just provided my former models in order to explain where I was. But I don't need to keep this structure. Again, sorry if I introduced this topic in the wrong way.

Comment: It's not about "offence" in any way. It;s about "approaching the problem differentlly" and accepting "different storage means". Don't move to MongoDB "because you think it's cool" or even because "someone says you should". Do it because "you **know** you need to". With luck, you might get an insightful response. But I personally think you stand more chance of a "stunning response" if you took the time to explain your use case and actually "tried something" beforehand. Learing by trial.

Comment: Agree. I should have been more clear. What is happening is that I was trying to build an app with Rails, and for a couple of reasons, decided to move to Meteor (at least for prototyping). And Meteor only works with MongoDB. So, I am definitely not moving to MongoDB because of the fad, but because I have to for the purpose of this project. Since I had designed the DB with Rails beforhand, I thought it could help to share what I had come up with in the question. I am more than happy to edit the question to give more context if that can help.

Comment: Anyhow enough chat. 1. Do some research and trial code. 2. Start asking questions about your research and trial code results. 3. Do so in "small bits" and not one "big" question. **Stellar** answers await. We love to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the design pattern is storing the calendar associated with each other in their own document. It will duplicate the calendar data but the user interaction will be very fast because as he log in he can see the calendar that you can fetch in one request.

```
          {userid : 'X1' , cal = [{} , {}]}
```

Only catch here is when anybody update the calendar you have to find all the document having the calendar and update it. So read is fast in this pattern but write is little slow.

Using proper index will make it faster to find the document having specific call

```
       db.collection.update({cal.id : 123},{});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Changing the `title` of a `calendar`is definitely not something that should be very frequent. We will allow it, for instance in case a `user` misspelled the `title` of his `calendar`, but this won't be a recurring task. However, the whole purpose of the app is to CRUD `posts`, within a calendar. In your example, would this be considered "writing" in the calendar? I believe it all depends on the schema we choose for the `one-to-many` association between `calendars` and `posts`, doesn't it?

Comment: @ThibaudClement i agree , we can keep the posts as collection independent and just put the calendar id and title in the user collection and after choosing the calendar he can add to the post collection. Even you can keep the meta data of the calendar in the collection